# Replacing a list of characters in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring

I want to replace a list of characters from my NSString and I do not want to use - (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement method multiple times. Is there any quick fix for this.

Comment: are the replacements to different characters or are all being replaced with one character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I use to get rid of any numbers from a string. It may not be the most efficient solution but it is the shortest.

```
 NSString* s = @"String to be fixed 3423";        
 NSCharacterSet* charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
 s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 2):

NSString instances cannot be changed. Either live with creating a new string (probably with the method you mentioned), or use an NSMutableString instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iOS 4.x you can use NSRegularExpression `stringByReplacingMatchesInString:`. The regular expression can catch all the strings you're trying to replace in a single go.